# external content type

Tags: bcs, external-list, multi-tenancy

We are a tenant in a larger SharePoint setup. I have tenant admin rights.
As a test I would like to create a list that originates from a SQL table.

I followed this guide: http://www.sharepoint.inf4web.com/217/external-content-type-ql-server-2008/
I followed all the steps in the article without any problems:

- create a user on database to be used for impersonation
- create External Content Type
- set access permission on service applications list
- create a Secure Store for the application
- create external list

When I open my newly created external list, I get a message "unable to display this web part to troubleshoot the problem, open this webpage in ..."
in SP Designer if I open the list I get an error and if I click the details button I get as error

> soap: ServerException of type
>   'Microsoft.Sharepoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. An
>   error has occured

My windows user has full rights on the db, and should have full tenant rights on SharePoint. The user I chose for impersonation has db-owner rights. So I figure it's not an authentication error, but rather something else.

any clues as to where to look to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was due to too many entries in the list.
I will investigate why the amount of entries in an external list is limited but meanwhile it does work on tables with less than 5 records.

Comment: quite annoying I can not mark my answer as solution until tomorrow.

Comment: Now you've hade two years without marking it though ;)

Comment: I've never managed to find out about how many entries I could connect with bsc.